# Searching for directories only

Tags: c, winapi, windows-7

```
int main(void) 
{   

    HANDLE hFoundFile;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA foundFileData;

    SetCurrentDirectory(TEXT("C:\\"));

    hFoundFile = FindFirstFileEx(TEXT("*"),FINDEX_INFO_LEVELS::FindExInfoBasic,&foundFileData ,FINDEX_SEARCH_OPS::FindExSearchLimitToDirectories ,NULL , NULL);

    do
    {
        wprintf(TEXT("%s\n"),foundFileData.cFileName);

    }
    while(FindNextFile(hFoundFile,&foundFileData));

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Why does it output also "regular" files, although `FINDEX_SEARCH_OPS::FindExSearchLimitToDirectories` option is explicitly passed to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to recursively traverse directories in C on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038912/how-to-recursively-traverse-directories-in-c-on-windows)

- note: Since the flag was added in 2001, any system prior to that point (e.g. Windows 2000, a NAS device built on an old version of Samba) will not support the flag. – Raymond Chen

  ```
  WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
  do {

  if (FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)




  }
  while(FindNextFile(hFindFile, &FindFileData));
  ```

and within your code:

```
int main(void) 
{   

    HANDLE hFoundFile;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA foundFileData;

    SetCurrentDirectory(TEXT("C:\\"));

    hFoundFile = FindFirstFileEx(TEXT("*"),FINDEX_INFO_LEVELS::FindExInfoBasic,&foundFileData ,FINDEX_SEARCH_OPS::FindExSearchLimitToDirectories ,NULL , NULL);

    do
    {
    if (foundFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        wprintf(TEXT("%s\n"),foundFileData.cFileName);

    }
    while(FindNextFile(hFoundFile,&foundFileData));

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```